# Why return is not honoring the value of variable in finally block?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch-finally

`finally` always gets executed last, so the statement `x = 3` should be executed last. But, when running this code, the value returned is 2.

Why?

```
class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(fina());
    }

    public static int fina()
    {
        int x = 0;
        try {
            x = 1;
            int a = 10/0;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            x = 2;
            return x;
        }
        finally
        {
            x = 3;
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the `finally` block is executed after the `catch` clause. Inside your `catch` you return `x`, and at that point its value is 2, which gets written to the stack as return value. Once `finally` overwrites the value of `x` with 3, the return value is already set to 2.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have a return statement in a catch block. Code is returning the value from that return statement even if the value is redefined in finally Block.

Comment: Well not quite, technically `finally` is still executed here. But it's not something which will change the outcome

Comment: @Rogue To demonstrate your point, the OP can do `return 3;` instead of `return x` in the `finally`, and it will return `3` instead of `2` because the `finally` still executes.  So this answer is wrong.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear in explaining. I meant the same thing what Max explained the return value was already set.

Comment: @Makgigrahul [edit] your answer to say what you mean if you don't think it is clear enough.